# ambiguous "use of unresolved identifier" error?

Tags: ios, swift, variables, xcode6, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm getting this use of unresolved identifier error which is pretty ambiguous to me, it appears on the following line :

[image]

however the "LUTToNSDataConverter" Is initialized in the following file :

```
//
//  LUTToNSDataConverter.h
//  imglyKit
//
//  Created by Carsten Przyluczky on 29/01/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 9elements GmbH. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface LUTToNSDataConverter : NSObject

+ (nullable NSData *)colorCubeDataFromLUTNamed:(nonnull NSString *)name interpolatedWithIdentityLUTNamed:(nonnull NSString *)identityName withIntensity:(float)intensity cacheIdentityLUT:(BOOL)shouldCache;

/*
 This method reads an LUT image and converts it to a cube color space representation.
 The resulting data can be used to feed an CIColorCube filter, so that the transformation 
 realised by the LUT is applied with a core image standard filter 
 */
+ (nullable NSData *)colorCubeDataFromLUT:(nonnull NSString *)name;

@end
```

I may add, this variable became "unresolved" when I dragged the whole folder up from Pods project target up to my regular project target, so Xcode can recognize it. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiler doesn't know `LUTToNSDataConverter` what is it? So please use like this

1. First import this file in your Current View Controller
2. And then call method on class, put **()** after class name like this
   **LUTToNSDataConverter().**

for ex

```
LUTToNSDataConverter(). colorCubeDataFromLUTNamed()// Pass your arguments here
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a Bridging-header because you are using Objective-C classes:

1. Add a header file to your project, named [MyProjectName]-Bridging-Header.h. This will be the single header file where you import any Objective-C code you want your Swift code to have access to.
2. In your project build settings, find Swift Compiler – Code Generation, and next to Objective-C Bridging Header add the path to your bridging header file, from the project’s root folder. So it could by MyProject/MyProject-Bridging-Header.h or simply MyProject-Bridging-Header.h if the file lives in the project root folder.

After that, you can add the imports to that file like that:

```
#import "YourHFile.h"
```

([source](https://bohemianpolymorph.wordpress.com/2014/07/11/manually-adding-a-swift-bridging-header/))